# Capacitance and Voltage of Capacitors

Tags: capacitor

I have looked all over the interwebs for a few good hours now, and I cannot find anything that simply explains a capacitor! I know that the capacitance of a capacitor is measured in uF, but what is the voltage of a capacitor? I have a small, hobby capacitor at my house and it is a 100 mF 16V capacitor. What is the difference between that and a 10uF 16V capacitor?

Schematic:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2feRson.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

So, as you can see the 2 caps are the same. If you charged part of the cap with fruit 1, as in Circuit 1, and then took out fruit 1, and replaced it with fruit 2, as seen in Circuit 2, without taking the cap out or discharging the cap, will the cap have 1400mV?

Comment: This should cover it - hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/capcon.html

Comment: See http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/18366/2191 and http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/80554/2191

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) The voltage of a capacitor is a potential difference that the two plates or sides of the capacitor develop when voltage is applied. This is the actual voltage.

2) The capacitor voltage rating is the maximum voltage practically allowed by the manufacturer for that part.

So, a 10uF 16V capacitor can be charged with a voltage up to 16V without damaging it, although getting close to 16V is bad engineering practice since its close to the limit of the part. The higher voltage could cause a dielectric breakdown which basically destroys the capacitor.

Please note that ceramic capacitors lose their capacitance when the voltage applied to the capacitor is close to the voltage rating. This can mean a loss of 50% or more of the capacitance. Therefore, you always want to have plenty of margin.

Comment: so... to get this straight, my 100uF capacitor can take in 16V and output 16V. What dos the 100uF have to do with anything?

Comment: @JustinChang: Capacitance and Voltage are related by charge. A certain capacitance has no relationship with voltage. Take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitance

Comment: OK thank you. Also, I need the capacitor to take in electricity in segments. So, if I hooked up a capacitor to a very minute voltage source, much smaller than the capacitance, and then I disconnected the voltage source and connected another one, will the capacitor take in both voltages and just add them together?

Comment: @JustinChang: No. The capacitor will charge to the higher of the voltages

Comment: Well then can you store the different charges into different capacitors and discharge it all onto one wire? If so, how would you do it?

Comment: In some way what you're asking about is a voltage doubler, or asks about it. It is possible with switches to charge, switch off and then switch all on at the same time. What are you trying to do?

Comment: My main purpose is to get the charges from various fruits into one storage device and to, on the flip of a switch or a press of a button, discharge all of the collected energy to run a small, low-power LED for a short time.

Comment: @JustinChang: You're better off using a supercapacitor to accumulate the charge, then use a circuit to boost it if needed.

Comment: I thought you said a capacitor takes the higher of two charges? How would a supercapacitor accumulate charge from two different sources of electricity? How would a circuit boost the electricity?

Comment: @JustinChang: I said the higher of the two voltages. Charge and voltage are not the same

Comment: So the capacitor will take in charges from two different sources?

Comment: @JustinChang: Please put a schematic of what you want to do.

Comment: I added a schematic

Comment: @JustinChang: No, the voltage will be never exceed 700mV. The voltage will build up to the maximum of 700mV with time as charge builds up in the capacitor. You need to consider some device such as a Joule thief to raise it above (or low voltage DC/DC booster)

Answer (score -1):

The voltage rating on a capacitor is the maximum amount of voltage that a capacitor can safely be exposed to and can store. capacitors is that they store X charge at X voltage meaning, they hold a certain size charge (1µF, 100µF, 1000µF, etc.) at a certain voltage (10V, 25V, 50V, etc.).

Comment: Capacitors don't store voltage, and the voltage rating has nothing to do with their ability to store energy at lower voltages.